# Grunt Copy files but not delete them

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

i have a UI Project that grunts the files and copies to the dist folder. 
The problem is  - the dist folder has some static js files on its own. (for eg library files )
So for eg : my UI folder has **1.js**, **2.js** 
My Dist file has  **1.js**,  **2.js** and also **lib1.js**, **lib2.js**.

When i run my run copy command, i am expecting to copy 1.js and 2.js and place it in my dist folder - which happens. But what it also does is- it deletes the other files and folders like lib1.js and lib2.js.

Anyway I can only  "Overwrite" the files but not delete anything else?

I use the following :

```
     {
       expand: true,
       cwd: '<%= globalConfig.path.build %>/js/pages/',
       src: ['*.js'],
       dest: '<%= globalConfig.path.dist %>/js/pages/'
   }
```

Comment: What's the actual Grunt task you are using? You've included the task config, but you've not indicated what it is that you are using.

Comment: @cartant i am running a task called as **'copy:{env}'**